# I can not get the content of my table jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

everyone

I'm desperately trying to figure out how to retrieve through a table the lines only those that have the input value filled.I want to be able to retrieve the first column(the text) and the second column (values of inputs)
 This is my html code.
Thank in advance.

```
<table id="TableSelect">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>price</th>
<th>qte</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tdQuantite"> Dell Latitude 7390</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5" data="qte" name="QUANTITE_300" value="" class="stock"> </td>
    <td class="tdQuantite">61</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="tdQuantite"> Dell Latitude 7490</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5" data="qte" name="QUANTITE_300" value="" class="stock"> </td>
    <td class="tdQuantite">61</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="tdQuantite"> Dell Latitude 5590</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5" data="qte" name="QUANTITE_300" value="" class="stock"> </td>
    <td class="tdQuantite">61</td>
</tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

It's is my code in jquery.

```
var Qte = $('#TableSelect tr:not(:first-child) td input').filter(function(){

      return $(this).val();

        })  ;

        console.log(Qte);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using any conditions in your filter function. You need to return whether value is empty or not.

```js
var Qte = $('#TableSelect tr:not(:first-child) td input').filter(function() {
  return $(this).val() != '';
}).map(function() {
  let parent = jQuery(this).closest("tr");
  return {
    value: parent.find("input").val(),
    text: parent.find(".tdQuantite").text().trim()
  }
});

console.log(Qte);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="TableSelect">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>price</th>
      <th>qte</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdQuantite"> Dell Latitude 7390</td>
      <td><input type="text" size="5" data="qte" name="QUANTITE_300" value="57" class="stock"> </td>
      <td class="tdQuantite">61</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="tdQuantite"> Dell Latitude 7490</td>
      <td><input type="text" size="5" data="qte" name="QUANTITE_300" value="" class="stock"> </td>
      <td class="tdQuantite">61</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="tdQuantite"> Dell Latitude 5590</td>
      <td><input type="text" size="5" data="qte" name="QUANTITE_300" value="459" class="stock"> </td>
      <td class="tdQuantite">61</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: They are using conditions.  $(this).val(); Is a truthy expression and evaluates to false if the value is empty.

Comment: Thanks to all of you I was able to unlock my program

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the values you want in addition to filtering the rows out:

```
var Qte = []

$('#TableSelect tr').each(function(){
      if($('td input', this).val()){
          Qte.push([$('td:first-child', this).text(), $('input', this).val()]
      }
})
console.log(Qte);
```

This pushes an array [first column text, input value] into Qte every time the input value is filled out.

Answer (score 0):

You should add in the *index* and *element* parameters to the filter function. Then from the element param you can access the cell values. Something along the lines of this should help:

```
var Qte = $('#TableSelect tr:not(:first-child)')
         .filter(function(i, element){

            var cell1 = element.childNodes[0].value;
            var cell2 = element.childNodes[1].value;

            return $(this).val();
          });
```

Now you should be getting the values you're after, that's assuming that your jQuery selector returns the appropriate  elements though.

You can *push* those values into an array if that's how you'd like to store them. Which can be done like this:

```
//outside the function
var values = [];

//from inside the function
var textAndValueArray = [cell1, cell2];

values.push(textAndValueArray);
return;
```

Now you have an array of arrays holding your text and value. This now gives you an easy means to loop over those values and you know each array index has a text and value array inside it.

Comment: `this` is the same as `element` in `.filter`

Comment: `element` is the `<input>` element. It has no childnodes.

Comment: The child nodes are `<td>`, they don't have `.value`. The input is the child of the second child node.

Answer (score 0):

You should be filtering the `<tr>`, not `<input>`. Then you can use `.map()` to get the contents of the columns you want from those rows.

```js
var qDE =
  $("#TableSelect tr:not(:first-child)").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("input").val();
  }).map(function() {
    return {
      item: $(this).find(".tdQuantite").first().text(),
      quantity: $(this).find("input").val()
    };
  }).get();
console.log(qDE);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="TableSelect">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>price</th>
      <th>qte</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdQuantite"> Dell Latitude 7390</td>
      <td><input type="text" size="5" data="qte" name="QUANTITE_300" value="10" class="stock"> </td>
      <td class="tdQuantite">61</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="tdQuantite"> Dell Latitude 7490</td>
      <td><input type="text" size="5" data="qte" name="QUANTITE_300" value="" class="stock"> </td>
      <td class="tdQuantite">61</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="tdQuantite"> Dell Latitude 5590</td>
      <td><input type="text" size="5" data="qte" name="QUANTITE_300" value="15" class="stock"> </td>
      <td class="tdQuantite">61</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This `$(this).find(".tdQuantite").text()` will find 2 <td> tags.

Comment: But `.text()` only returns the text of the first one.

Comment: Your code snippet returns :   item: "Dell Latitude 739061" vice "Dell Latitude 7390" It's pulling in both, as per the documentation of .text()  _Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants._